# Conditional Expectation of E(2X+Y|X-Y=1)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I met these two problems. The first question reads: what is $E(X|X+Y=1)$ 
given that $X$ and $Y$ are both independent standard normal random variables. 
The second reads that $X$ and $Y$ are correlated standard normal random variables at a correlation of $\rho$, then what is $E(2X+Y|X-Y=1)?$

I tried to first find the sample space of given condition that $X+Y=1$ and $X-Y=1$. I realized that they are both sample space with $0$ probability since the two space are reduced to $\rm I\!R^1$ from $\rm I\!R^2$, therefore the conditions should have $0$ probability. In that case

$E(X|X+Y=1) = E(1-Y) = 1-0\quad$ since $\quad Y\subset    \rm I\!R^1$

$E(2X+Y|X-Y=1) = E(2X+X-1) = E(3X-1) = -1$ since $\quad X\subset    \rm I\!R^1$

are these answers correct?

Comment: No, these are not right. While it's true that $E(X\mid X+Y=1) = E(1-Y\mid X+Y=1),$ you can't just drop the conditional.

Comment: What is the probability of $P(X+Y=1)$?

Comment: It's zero. I'm not sure why you think that leads to what you wrote (which is wrong... the answer is $1/2.$)

Comment: I tried to find $P(X<=x|X+Y=1)$ then $f_X(x|X+Y=1)$ then the expectation.

Comment: Have you learned bivariate normal? Since $(X, X+Y)$ are bivariate normal, you can apply the conditional mean formula directly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_conditional_expectation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal. Then $X-Y$ and $X+Y$ are independent. Moreover,
\begin{align*}
E\big(X \mid X+Y=1 \big) &= \frac{1}{2}E\big( (X+Y)+(X-Y) \mid X+Y=1\big)=\frac{1}{2},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
E\big(2X+Y \mid X-Y=1 \big) &=E\big(X \mid X-Y=1 \big) +E\big(X+Y \mid X-Y=1 \big)\\
&=\frac{1}{2} + E(X+Y) = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}